# jQuery - thousands seperator on html string

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to add a thousands separator for the `.htm(price * num)` result by adding `.digits();` to the `var sub`. How do I get the thousands seperator to work on the result of the `var sub`? Since they are not `val` do I need to convert the result into a number before adding the `digits();` function?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.fn.digits = function() {
    return this.each(function() {
      $(this).val(
        $(this)
        .val()
        .replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+(?!\d))/g, "$1,")
      );
    });
  };
  var total = $(".slider__total").html();
  var sold = $(".sold").html();
  var available = total - sold;
  var price = $(".cost").html();
  var num = $("#num").html();
  $(".item__available").html(available);
  var sub = $("#slider_subtotal")
    .html(price * num)
    .digits();
  $(".qty").attr({
    max: available
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
sold<span class="sold">3</span>total<span class="slider__total">10</span>available<span class="item__available"></span><input type="range" min="1" value="1" class="qty" name='quantity' oninput="num.value = this.value"><output id="num">0</output>unit:
$
<span class="cost">500</span>subtotal: $<span id="slider_subtotal">0</span>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the built-in `Number.prototype.toLocaleString()` method instead:

```
(1234567.567).toLocaleString('en-US') // 1,234,567.567
```

Or - if you prefer - you can also keep it "local" to the current user by omitting the first argument: `(1234567.567).toLocaleString()` will refer to the browsers regional settings and will return a suitable local number string.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var total = $(".slider__total").text();
  var sold = $(".sold").text();
  var available = total - sold;
  var price = $(".cost").text();
  
  $(".item__available").html(available);
  $(".qty").attr({max: available})
           .on("input",function(){
    $("#slider_subtotal").text((price * this.value).toLocaleString("en-US",{style:'currency', currency:'USD'}));
    $("#num").text(this.value)
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
sold<span class="sold">37</span>
total<span class="slider__total">103</span>
available<span class="item__available"></span>
<input type="range" min="1" value="1" class="qty" name='quantity'>
<output id="num">0</output>
unit:$<span class="cost">123.4</span>
subtotal: <span id="slider_subtotal">$0</span>
```